# Why doesn't my machine tell me it's memory type?

Tags: ram

I wanted to see my memory type information (ex: DDR2, DDR3, DDR4) with the commands below, but it doesn't say. What's the reason? Is there a way I can know?

```
$ sudo lshw -short -C memory                                                                                                                                           
H/W path           Device     Class          Description
========================================================
/0/0                          memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/5e                         memory         32GiB System Memory
/0/5e/0                       memory         8GiB DIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/5e/1                       memory         DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/5e/2                       memory         8GiB DIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/5e/3                       memory         DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/5e/4                       memory         8GiB DIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/5e/5                       memory         DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/5e/6                       memory         8GiB DIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
/0/5e/7                       memory         DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/6c                         memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/6d                         memory         1536KiB L2 cache
/0/6e                         memory         15MiB L3 cache

$ sudo dmidecode --type memory                                                                                                                               [140/1342]
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0x000f0570
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x005E, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 512 GB
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Number Of Devices: 8

Handle 0x0060, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x005E
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 72 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_A1
        Bank Locator: NODE 1
        Type: Other
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 2133 MHz
        Manufacturer: Samsung
        Serial Number: 9203CE6C
        Asset Tag: DIMM_A1_AssetTag
        Part Number: M378A1G43DB0-CPB   
        Rank: 2
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz

Handle 0x0062, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x005E
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_A2
        Bank Locator: NODE 1
        Type: Other
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: NO DIMM
        Serial Number: NO DIMM
        Asset Tag: NO DIMM
        Part Number: NO DIMM
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0063, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x005E
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 72 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_B1
        Bank Locator: NODE 1
        Type: Other
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 2133 MHz
        Manufacturer: Samsung
        Serial Number: 9203CE36
        Asset Tag: DIMM_B1_AssetTag
        Part Number: M378A1G43DB0-CPB   
        Rank: 2
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz

Handle 0x0065, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x005E
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_B2
        Bank Locator: NODE 1
        Type: Other
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: NO DIMM
        Serial Number: NO DIMM
        Asset Tag: NO DIMM
        Part Number: NO DIMM
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0066, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x005E
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 72 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_C1
        Bank Locator: NODE 1
        Type: Other
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 2133 MHz
        Manufacturer: Samsung
        Serial Number: 9203CE7C
        Asset Tag: DIMM_C1_AssetTag
        Part Number: M378A1G43DB0-CPB   
        Rank: 2
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz

Handle 0x0068, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x005E
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_C2
        Bank Locator: NODE 1
        Type: Other
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: NO DIMM
        Serial Number: NO DIMM
        Asset Tag: NO DIMM
        Part Number: NO DIMM
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0069, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x005E
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 72 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_D1
        Bank Locator: NODE 1
        Type: Other
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 2133 MHz
        Manufacturer: Samsung
        Serial Number: 9203CE7E
        Asset Tag: DIMM_D1_AssetTag
        Part Number: M378A1G43DB0-CPB   
        Rank: 2
        Configured Clock Speed: 2133 MHz

Handle 0x006B, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x005E
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_D2
        Bank Locator: NODE 1
        Type: Other
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: NO DIMM
        Serial Number: NO DIMM
        Asset Tag: NO DIMM
        Part Number: NO DIMM
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
```

Comment: Not sure why it's not specified, however they are all DDR4-2133MHz.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it doesn't show when you run the command `sudo dmidecode --type memory`.

However, a quick google search of the part number **M378A1G43DB0-CPB** shows it is DDR4.

Near the end of page 6 of the following document, the product is listed under **4.7 288Pin DDR4 Non ECC UDIMM**

[webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.samsung.com](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/file/product/DDR4_Product_guide_Aug14.pdf)